# Xcode 13.4.1 build error. Multiple commands produce '/Volumes/workspace/DerivedData/

Tags: ios, xcode, build, deriveddata

I'm trying to build one project after 7 months but continuously getting these errors.

I tried,

1. Delete derived data, clean build but still same error
2. Tried to change workspace settings - New Build system

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue fixed:**

In my project, I had an extension target with the same `Product Module Name` as the main project target `Product Module Name`.

**How to fixed it?**

Select `target` -> `Build settings` -> `Packaging` and set `Product Module Name` differ from app's target `Product Module Name`.